# How to draw markers inside a specific radius for google maps in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I have a Google Map fragment on my android application.

I have markers drawn on the map which represent places of interest and I have an extra functionality that draws a circle on the center with a radius defined by the user.

What I want to do is that only the markers which are contained inside this circle shall be displayed on map. I am using the Circle object, from Google maps Shapes, to draw the circle.

The problem is that, although the center of the circle is defined in Latitude/Longitude coordinates, it's radius is defined in meters. So how can I calculate if a position of a place in LatLng is contained within a radius defined in meters?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is to calculate if two `LatLngs` are closer to each other than radius.

For that you can use [`Location.distanceBetween`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]%29).

See the [`Circle.contains` function here](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions/blob/develop/android-maps-extensions/src/main/java/com/androidmapsextensions/impl/DelegatingCircle.java#L35-L40) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you are going to have to do is test all points and use ray casting to test the points against sides the circle.

If you find only 1 collision with a side then the point is inside the circle, if you find 2 collisions spots then it is outside the circle.

It sounds intimidating but its not too bad once you understand it

Here is excellent [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test) on what is involved. I used a combination of the first and second answer to something similar